# ¿Como visualizo ContextMenu desde un FloatingActionButton?

Tags: android

Acabo de retomar la programación Android y estoy absolutamente perdido. Ya no me acuerdo de nada.

Tengo un FloatingActionButton e intento visualizar un ContextMenu en onClick de FloatingActionButton.

Por favor alguien me guía completamente o me lo explica que debo hacer. Muchas gracias.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
    // no se que poner
    }
});}


    @Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_flotante, menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.red:
            // accion1
            return true;
        case R.id.blue:
            // accion2
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Después pongo un menu_flotante.xml en la ruta res/menu/

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item android:id="@+id/red"
            android:title="@string/red" />
        <item android:id="@+id/blue"
            android:title="@string/blue" />
    </group>
</menu>
```

Comment: Bienvenido, recuerda que es demasiado importante agregar lo que trataste o investigaste, revisa [ask] y edita tu pregunta, saludos.

Comment: Gracias Jorgesys. Creo que lo que he añadido será suficiente.  Digo, yo, tampoco es que este seguro del todo.  Saludos.